# Android in app billing claims to not be supported using sample code

Tags: android, android-service, in-app-billing

I have followed the sample code for in app billing for android found at : http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html

I have integrated that code into my application - and followed all steps as appropriate including signing apk - uploading, creating in app products list etc.

For some reason When my app these lines in the onCreate method :

```
 Log.e("sc2","About to check if billing is supported");
    // Check if billing is supported.
    ResponseHandler.register(mDungeonsPurchaseObserver);
    if (!mBillingService.checkBillingSupported()) {
    Log.e("sc2","failed check for billing supported");
        showDialog(DIALOG_CANNOT_CONNECT_ID);
    }

    if (!mBillingService.checkBillingSupported(Consts.ITEM_TYPE_SUBSCRIPTION)) {
         Log.e("sc2","failed check for billing supported subscriptions");
        showDialog(DIALOG_SUBSCRIPTIONS_NOT_SUPPORTED_ID);
    }
    Log.e("sc2","Finished checking if billing is supported");
```

Neither dialogs show - suggesting everything is bound correctly to the market billing service.

However on the PurchaseObserver callback these lines :

```
 private class SC2PurchaseObserver extends PurchaseObserver {
    public SC2PurchaseObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(UpgradesActivity.this, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingSupported(boolean supported, String type) {
        if (Consts.DEBUG) {
            Log.e("sc2", "supported: " + supported+":"+type);
        }
        if (type == null || type.equals(Consts.ITEM_TYPE_INAPP)) {
            if (supported) {
                restoreDatabase();
                mBuyButton.setEnabled(true);
                mEditPayloadButton.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                showDialog(DIALOG_BILLING_NOT_SUPPORTED_ID);
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Consts.ITEM_TYPE_SUBSCRIPTION)) {
            mCatalogAdapter.setSubscriptionsSupported(supported);
        } else {
            showDialog(DIALOG_SUBSCRIPTIONS_NOT_SUPPORTED_ID);
        }
    }
```

The log messages appear as follows:

supported: false:null
supported: false:subs

Suggesting the android market callback has said neither in app billing standard, or subscriptions is enabled....

Can somebody please explain why the first checks may not be failing - yet the call back messages appear as they do!?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the BILLING_REQUEST_API_VERSION when you create the Request bundle. Method below is from the sample project

```
protected Bundle makeRequestBundle(String method) {
       Bundle request = new Bundle();
       request.putString(Consts.BILLING_REQUEST_METHOD, method);
       request.putInt(Consts.BILLING_REQUEST_API_VERSION, 2);
       request.putString(Consts.BILLING_REQUEST_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
       return request;
}
```